# if i put a toast message in onCreate() function, will message be printed infinitely?

Tags: android, oncreate, android-toast

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listen();
    }

    public void listen() {
        Toast a = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"HI",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        a.show();
    }
}
```

Will this goes on printing the HI string..?

Comment: Why would it keep printing it? It would only be called once, won't it?

Comment: Sir, im new to android, so i am asking..To make the items in the listview clickable, the onsetitemlistener is always put in the oncreate method..so that it will continuously listen which item is being clicked..am i right?

Comment: OnCreate() 
is called whenever your activity is created, and at that time, this toast will be displayed. 
Now, how many times the activity is created depends on your application flow.

What makes you think that it would be displayed infinitely.

Comment: @AswinJacob : the underlying implementation of onclicklistener keeps listening to the click events because it;s purpose is to do so. In case of Toast, it's purpose is to just display the toast once.

Comment: Is there any case when the item in the listview is not showing any click effects even if i add the onsetitemlistener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No It won't.
However, `onCreate()` function is called somewhat more often than you think!
(like on Screen Rotation and more ...)

Checkout [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and learn when `onCreate()` is called.